# How can I freeze a question I created, so no one can post in it for a while?

Tags: discussion

I recently asked a question on Math.SE that hasn't received answers. I plan to do some major edits to it, after which maybe someone will be able to answer it. In the mean time, I don't want new posts added to the question, because they won't fit when I am done editing the question (which can be a couple of days from now). Can I somehow freeze the question?

For now I'll delete it, and later undelete it. Is this appropriate?

Comment: For major edits, you can also try to use [our sandbox](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/4666/sandbox-for-drafts-of-long-complex-answers) to "prep" your edits and copy it over once you've decided that it has reached a good final state.

Comment: Related: [edit and rephrase or ask new question?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/2814/)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If the edits are significant enough that it *entirely* changes the question, you should simply delete and ask it as a new question, as otherwise would look confusing in the post history.  Also, you should delete and re-ask if there are comments which would no longer be applicable to the edited question (and none that *would* still be applicable), as that saves the mods time dealing with obsolete flags.

Other than that, I don't see anything wrong with what you're doing.